# Given list of files names, return list of lists of files with same content - interview question

Tags: algorithm, performance, file

You are given a list of file names, and need to return a list that every item in it is a list with files that have same content. Also important to mention is that those files have a very large size.

For example:
If we got the list `{"file1", "file2", "file3", "file4", "file5"}` as input, and we know that `file1.content()==file2.content()==file3.content, file4.content==file5.content(), file3.content()!=file4.content()` , so the output should be:
 `{{"file1", "file2", "file3"}, {"file4", "file5"}}`.

I said to the interviewer we can create HashMap that hash the files by their `sha512` hash code. Then we can iterate over the keys in the map, for each key we iterate over the list mapped to it for comparing pairs of files in the list (for checking that indeed each pair of files have same content).

The only problem I had with this solution, is that I didn't return list of lists as mention above, but just pairs of duplicate files. That means, for the example above - I returned this:
`{{"file1", "file2"}, {"file2", "file3"}, {"file4", "file5"}}`.

I just didn't find an efficient way of creating the wanted output.
For the example above, my HashMap could potentially (although not very likely) have just one key that is mapped to all of the input files.
For scenarios like these, I couldn't find an algorithm to return the desired list in last than `O(n^2)` comparisons (`n` is the number of files in the list).

Do you have an efficient way of returning the desired list, given that you allready have a HashMap of `sha512` keys mapped to list of files with that `sha512` hash code?

Comment: No time for even re-read the algo problem, but first check file size, before creating any hash.

Comment: @Kaiido, I can also check the size - but that doesn't change the problem that I have.

Answer (score 1):

So you have files: "file1" through "file5". Let's say you compute the sha512 for each, and you end up with this:

```
 Name                SHA512
file1   000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F
file2   0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA98765432101963DEADBEEFF00BA977345417B00BE5
file3   000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F
file4   0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA98765432101963DEADBEEFF00BA977345417B00BE5
file5   000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F
```

If sort the list by SHA512, you have:

```
file1   000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F
file3   000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F
file5   000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F
file2   0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA98765432101963DEADBEEFF00BA977345417B00BE5
file4   0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA98765432101963DEADBEEFF00BA977345417B00BE5
```

The files in the list are now grouped by hash value. It's a trivial matter to iterate over the list and output the groups.

As the OP pointed out in comments, there's no guarantee that two files with the same SHA512 hash have equal contents. So after you've grouped the files by hash, you have to compare each against the other.

Or, you could use MD5 for the initial hash, and group the files together by their MD5 hashes. Then, for files that have the same MD5 hash, compute the SHA512 hash. If two files have the same MD5 hash and the same SHA512 hash, it's highly unlikely that they are different. But if you want to be sure, you have to compare each file, byte-by-byte against the other files.

Comment: But the thing is that files with same SHA512 value don't necessarily have same content (small chances for it, but still possible). You still need to compare them by content for knowing at 100% that they have equal content. How do you do it if for example, all 5 files have same SHA512?

Comment: @JimMischel _it's highly unlikely that they have equal contents_: I am sure you want to rephrase it

Answer (score 0):

There is some heuristic in comparing the files before hashing as mentioned in comments (such as files checking file size). By the way, if the hash of each file is given, you can sort hash files (in O(n log(n)), and iterate over the hashes and bucketize the files (in O(n)). Therefore, it can be done in O(n log(n)) in the worst case.

Comment: By what parameter you want to sort those hash files (those are just strings represents names)?

Comment: @John The hash value is a string. You can sort it by dictionary rule or you can map the hash string to an integer value and sort them.

Comment: I still didn't understand what you mean. If for the example above I have just one key (sha512 key) mapped to the list {"file1", "file2", "file3", "file4", "file5"} - how exactly you suggest to sort it?